How write in a partitioned IcebergTable using Managed IcebergIO?
I was following the Dataflow documentation to write in a Iceberg table (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/write-to-iceberg)
When i try to insert in a partitioned data, i get the following stacktrace

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Partition must not be null when creating data writer for partitioned spec
    at org.apache.iceberg.relocated.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:143)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.Parquet$DataWriteBuilder.build(Parquet.java:704)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.iceberg.RecordWriter.<init>(RecordWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.iceberg.RecordWriter.<init>(RecordWriter.java:47)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.iceberg.WriteUngroupedRowsToFiles$WriteUngroupedRowsToFilesDoFn.createAndInsertWriter(WriteUngroupedRowsToFiles.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.iceberg.WriteUngroupedRowsToFiles$WriteUngroupedRowsToFilesDoFn.getWriterIfPossible(WriteUngroupedRowsToFiles.java:242)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.iceberg.WriteUngroupedRowsToFiles$WriteUngroupedRowsToFilesDoFn.processElement(WriteUngroupedRowsToFiles.java:258)


After some time debugging, it seems that the partition information is not being set to Parquet Data Writer.
I've opened a bug in: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/31943
Have anyone found a solution? Am i missing a property or this is a bug?
